# Getting parameters passed in the ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am trying to make a post call from a simple html page to a nodejs, express server which saves the values to a mongo collection.

I am passing two post parameters ie name and email, but at the server I am not getting the passed values.

Server says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined. What might be the issue.

**This is my html file**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br> User Name :
        <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName">
        <br>
        <br>Email :
        <input type="text" id="emailId" name="emailId">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="addAttrs" value="Add" onclick="addUser()">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/client.js"></script>
</html>
```

**This is my client side ajax post call at client.js**

```
function addUser() {
    var usrName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var usrEmail = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
    console.log('User name :' + usrName + " Email :" + usrEmail);
    var obj = {
        'userName': usrName,
        'userEmail': usrEmail
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/adduser',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('user created , info :' + data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('User creation failed :' + data);
        }
    });
}
```

**This is my server index.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static('public'));
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
var myCollection;
var db;         
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("connected to the mongoDB !");
        myCollection = db.collection('user_collection');
    });
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
})

module.exports = app;
```

**This is where I handle the request at router.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/views', 'index.html'));
});

router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({}, {}, function(e, docs) {
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist": docs
        });
    });
});

router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    console.log(req.body);
    var userName = req.body.userName;
    var userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.insert({
        "username": userName,
        "email": userEmail
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        } else {
            response = {
                message: 'user created successfully',
                status: 200
            };
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `console.log(req.body)` inside the action. What output is there?

Comment: console.log(req.body) prints undefined.

Comment: Is a body parser configured? For good measure also set the content type on the `$.ajax` request: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. Something is causing the post body to not be parsed into an object. Check `req.params`, but you will really want to correct this so it goes into `req.body` instead.

Comment: still getting same response after adding contentType , I have edited the post  with entire code. Do I have to add seperate body-parser for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should send a json instead of string.Make your ajax like this

> Remove `JSON.stringify()` or make that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` since you are sending a string (ie:**typeof req.body is string**) instead.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/adduser',
        method: 'POST',
        data:obj,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('user created , info :' + data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('User creation failed :' + data);
        }
    });
```

> and At your server side. use `app.use(bodyParser.json());` this is very important to parse application/json type.
>
> Now i guess i will be working for you.

Comment: Thanks , JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) worked like charm.

Comment: welcome...but there is no point when your obj is already a json!